# php form validation issues - cannot print to header

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a php form that saves the info to my database and sends an email upon completion. however it will not validate the fields to see if they are null, instead it prints both the set and not set options.  Any ideas as to why this could be happening? It worked perfectly before i added the form field validation to it.

As a side note it works in FF and Chrome due to the html 5 aria-required, but not in IE

html

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="register1.php" method="post">
 <label for='Cname'>Camper Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="Cname" maxlength="50" value="" required aria-required=true />
 <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="submitform" />
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Continue to Camp Selction"/>
</form>
```

php

```
<?php
 //include the connection file

 require_once('connection.php');

 //save the data on the DB and send the email

 if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'submitform')
 {

   //recieve the variables
$Cname = $_POST['Cname'];

//form validation (this is where it all breaks)
if (isset($Cname)) {
    echo "This var is set so I will print.";
}
else {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("please enter the required fields");</script>'; 
}
//save the data on the DB (this part works fine)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using PHP's empty function

[PHP.Net Manual Empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

You can update your code to the following:

```
if(!empty($Cname)) {
    echo "This var is set so I will print.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $Cname = isset($_POST['Cname']) ? $_POST['Cname'] : null;
    if (isset($Cname)) {
        echo "This var is set so I will print.";
    }

    // OR

    if (isset($_POST['Cname'])) {
        // Perform your database action here...
    }
?>
```

Comment: it's still throwing this error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at register1.php:37) in register1.php on line 105

Comment: Ok start your output buffer at the top of register1.php like `<?php ob_start(); ?>` before any other element.

Comment: this helped when i added the flush to the end as well

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need an "exit()" in the else?